# C++ abstract class cannot be instantiated

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, abstract-class

I have this abstract class

```
class ImageIO {
protected:
    ImageIO() {}
public:
    virtual bool load(const std::string & filename, const std::string & format) = 0;
    virtual bool save(const std::string & filename, const std::string & format) = 0;
}
```

And the implementation

```
class Image : public Array2D<Color>, public ImageIO {

private:
    static int case_insensitive(string s) {
        transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);

        if (s.compare("ppm") == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

public:
    bool load(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) {
        if (case_insensitive(format)) {
            float* data = ReadPPM(filename.c_str(), (int*)width, (int*)height);

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < width * height; i++, j += 3) {
                buffer[i] = Color(data[j], data[j + 1], data[j + 2]);
            }

            delete[] data;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool save(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) {
        if (case_insensitive(format)) {

            float* data = new float[width * height * 3];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < width * height; i++, j += 3) {
                data[j] = buffer[i].x;
                data[j + 1] = buffer[i].y;
                data[j + 2] = buffer[i].z;
            }

            bool write_check = WritePPM(data, width, height, filename.c_str());
            delete[] data;
            return write_check;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

And I keep getting an abstract class cannot be instantiated error if I try this

`Image test = Image();`

in my main.
I've also tried declaring t=those two methods in a header file

```
class Image : public Array2D<Color>, public ImageIO {

private:
    static int case_insensitive(std::string);
public:
    bool ImageIO::load(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format);
    bool ImageIO::save(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format);
};
```

but then I get unresolved external symbol errors. Is there a problem in the way I'm implementing the two functions or in how my declaring the class?

EDIT: If I declare those two methods in the header file then the error is:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall image::Image::[image::ImageIO]::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@?QImageIO@image@@Image@2@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall image::Image::[image::ImageIO]::save(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?save@?QImageIO@image@@Image@2@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function _main
```

If I don't the error is

```
error C2259: 'image::Image': cannot instantiate abstract class
```

I also added override and nothing changes.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of typos that prevent it from compiling. For example at the closing braces of your ImageIO class declaration and your "virtual bool load" function declaration the semicolon is missing. It's also worth mentioning that you probably should use the override keyword even when the base class function is pure virtual for readability.

Comment: Use `override` specifier after declaration of overriding methods in derived classes. It will make sure you are actually overriding them.

Comment: How are you compiling this and what is the projects directory structure? What file is `Image` and `ImageIO` declared and defined in?

Comment: I agree with the override specifier: it saves n awful lot of time.  Since you're using multiple inheritance,  are you sure that there is nothing abstract in Array2D and that this class doesn't also provice some load and save ?

Comment: At the very least, show the exact and complete text of any error message. For all we know, there are pure virtual functions in `Array2D` that `Image` fails to implement. The error message should mention which functions the compiler believes are missing.

Comment: Hmm... going by your edit, there's one more thing you might want to test: What happens if you define the methods inline, in your header file?  A [quick test with dummy `Array2D` and `Color` types](https://godbolt.org/z/QB5cBt) and slight typo fixes (added semicolon after `ImageIO` definition, added `std` namespace to `Image::case_sensitive()`'s `string` parameter) suggests that MSVC shouldn't have any problems with the code shown, which in turn suggests that the problem may be in something you haven't shown and/or changed for your example.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer the question about unresolved external symbols, you don't need the `ImageIO` parent specifier on the save/load functions. You are declaring that `Image` itself has those functions, which override the abstract functions on the parent. You will then need to specify `Image` when implementing them in the cpp file.

Image.hpp

```
class Image : public Array2D<Color>, public ImageIO {

private:
    static int case_insensitive(std::string);
public:
    bool load(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) override;
    bool save(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) override;
};
```

Image.cpp

```
bool Image::load(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) {
    if (case_insensitive(format)) {

        //etc.
    }

    return false;
}

bool Image::save(const std::string& filename, const std::string& format) {
    if (case_insensitive(format)) {

       //etc.
    }

    return false;
}
```